# setup.py not correctly including package_data

Tags: python, setup.py

I am trying to include spreadsheets (.xlsx) and text files (.txt) in a directory (with an **init**.py file, so it is a package).  I can get the .txt files to install properly but CANNOT get the .xlsx files to appear in the package directly after performing a pip install.  I have tried with and without MANIFEST.in file and include_package_data=True in setup.py.

My package structure is as follows:

```
- setup.py
- requirements.py
- myproject
    - __init__.py
    - main.py
    - Data
         - __init__.py
         - test.xlsx
         - test.txt
```

And my setup.py files is as follows:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='myproject',
    packages=find_packages(),
    package_data={'myproject': ['Data/*.xlsx', 'Data/*.txt']}
)
```

I install using pip and when I look at the package directory, all of the files appear as expected, except for the .xlsx files.  It is strange that the .txt file shows up but the .xlsx file(s) do not.

I've seen tutorials, documentation and SO posts on this topic and have tried all of those suggestions.

Comment: Is `myproject.py` a file or a directory? Is it really named `myproject.py`?

Comment: Oh, my apology.  it is just "myproject" and it is a package directory.  And no, it isn't really called that.  It's "g***_utils".  File and directory names have been sanitized for the purposes of this SO post.  I have edited the original post to correct this.

Comment: OK, and what pip command do you use to install? Do you install from the source directory, from the sdist, or from the wheel?

Comment: I figured it out.  I was installing from github and for some reason the spreadsheet files were not making it into github when I committed the rest of the project files.

Comment: Actually, no.  The spreadsheet files were not being pushed to github.  That's fixed and the files are installed in the package directory after the pip install.  But I still cannot access the files.  The code to access the files is:

import importlib.resources as pkg_resources
import pandas as pd
file = [x for x in pkg_resources.contents('Data')][0]
stream = pkg_resources.read_binary('Data', file)
f = pd.read_excel(stream)

I get ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Data' even though Data is in fact a package directory with an __init__.py file in it.  I must be missing something.

Comment: One more note about the code referenced above.  It DOES work when being run from within the project itself.  When pushed to github and then installed on another computer using pip, the file structure is right but I get the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Data'

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, sinoroc.  Not being able to find 'Data' was resolved by editing to read pkg_resources.contents('myproject.Data').   But now I cannot figure out how to sort the xlsx files in Data so that I can pull only the most recent version.  I tried sorted([x for x in pkg_resources.contents('Data')], key=os.path.getmtime, reverse=True)[0] but because pkg_resources.contents() returns strings and not path objects, the os.path.getmtime fails.  If I upgrade to 3.9, I think I can use pkg_resources.files() to get path objects, but I haven't tried that yet - hoping there's an easier way

Comment: ***1.*** I have no idea if the timestamps are kept as-is once the files go through the whole processes of packaging and installing on target machine. ***2.*** Strictly speaking, you don't always get access to an actual on-disk file, in particular in cases when the code is being imported from a zipped archive. ***3.*** It is an entirely different question, so feel free to post a new question to address this.